# What tool can I use to automatically break long lines of PHP code?

Tags: linux, php, code-beautification

I'm rewriting a lot of old PHP code at my work and we have decided to enforce the PSR12 standard. I find myself wasting a ton of time breaking long lines of code to comply with the 120 characters hard limit of PHP_Codesniffer tool.

I'm using the PHP plugin for Prettier (https://github.com/prettier/plugin-php) and this works pretty well on only-PHP files, however, it can't handle PHP and HTML mixed together.

Is there a tool or IDE that can wrap long lines of PHP code for me? I'm working on the Linux system.

Comment: What OS must the tool run on? What is your price limit if it comes to paid software?